# CSS only solution: hide element in overflow hidden element, that partially falls behind another fixed element

Tags: html, css

I have a collapsed menu with a dynamic number of items (green tiles in image)

I also have a fixed item that needs to be in the bottom of the menu - always.

This works fine, but now the menu items are cut off sometimes halfway through depending on screen size. How do I make sure that I hide the items which are cut through halfway?

I have attached an image which explains it clearly.

I know that I can do it with JavaScript, but I am looking for a CSS solution if it exists. If such a solution does not exist, that is an answer as well.[image]

Comment: Have you tried working with media-queries?

Comment: can you share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media queries will allow you to set designated styling to different media sizes (width and height of a device screen)

media queries are widely used in frameworks like bootstrap and such and is considered a CSS solution.

for more info : [Responsive Web Design](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

by this you will able to hide certein element of choosing with a simple `display: hidden` and it will affect an element only within the bounds of that media.

for example:

```
.div {
  height: 80px;
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 995px) , screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  .div {
    color: white;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 678px) , screen and (max-height: 300px) {
  .div {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

this will maintain height but will change color on each query.

hope my explanation is clear.

you could also use !important on each change if you don't want to mess with css loading order i.e
`color: white !important;`

and this will override any color style before this one was declared.

Comment: I am familiar with media queries, you're right, maybe this is the way to go. If the green blocks are 80px high, do I have to add a media query rule for every 80px step in screen size from smallest to largest expected pixel screen size? Or is there a way to create a dynamic rule?

Comment: no. you can style it without any media queries and than on queries implement only addons to style; meaning - if you have on your normal div height: 80px it will be saved throughout all the media queries unless you specifically change the divs height on each query. but if you just play with hidden and such it should suffice. kind of implementing two classes on same div. one doesn't erase the other unless specificaly stated

Comment: i've edited my answer to give a small example following your question mate. :)

Comment: I think CSS only this is the way to go, and just to support a fixed number of screen height ranges